# Referring to variables, using variables

Tags: vb.net, variables

I'm creating a game, which will store maps on separate files.
This is done in that file using variables as such:

```
Public X1Y1 = "idle"
```

Containing the location and pixel information for my screen drawing engine.
To draw each pixel, I need to cycle through all of these variables.

I wanted to do that as shown, but I can't figure out how to refer to the variables in the map file
(eg: `X1Y1` or `X5Y4`), using a variable which stores the name of the variable required (`pos`).

```
  Dim targetmap As SplashMap = New SplashMap()
    For rowcount = 0 To targetmap.xRes Step 1
        'for each row on the map
        For columncount = 0 To targetmap.yRes Step 1
            'place the pixel in each column
            Dim pos = "X" & rowcount & "Y" & columncount
            PlacePixel(pos, targetmap.'var <- problem, vbNull)
          'call engine(Pixel Location, Pixel information stored in var, special control instruction (unused)) 
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: It sounds like the data structure you're looking for is a `Dictionary`.

Comment: I'll have a quick look into it, could you outline how they work?

Comment: http://vb.net-informations.com/collections/dictionary.htm

Comment: No, it sounds like you want a 2-dimensional array: `Dim XY(5, 5) As Integer : XY(rowcount, columncount) = 42`.

Comment: Thank you, in fact this is the method somebody mentioned to me yesterday, and I've been tinkering with since. I think this will be the method I use :)

Comment: I never followed up: Utilise an array, as oppose to individual variables.